# In Django how to create a "super symmetrical" relation on a ManyToMany self relation

Tags: django, many-to-many, admin

I have this model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

So `friends` relation is *symmetrical*. So if you're my friend, I'm your friend.

What I would like also is that all my friend's friends be automatically my friends. Example:

If A and B are friends (AB, BA) and we add a new friend C to B, C will be automatically added also to A (AB, BA, BC, CB, AC, CA). If we remove C from B, C will automatically be removed from A.

I need this to work in a normal Admin page. When submitting a form, for a ManyToManyField, Django call first `clean()`, erasing all relations related to the current instance, then `add()`, adding all the relations coming from the form.

I was able to get the good behavior when adding a new relation with this code (but it doesn't work when removing relation):

```
def add_friends(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        if len(pk_set) > 1:
            pk = pk_set.pop()
            next = People.objects.get(pk=pk)
            next.friends.add(*pk_set)

m2m_changed.connect(add_friends, sender=People.friends.through)
```

When searching for solutions, I have hard time not creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The problem was that I needed to clear all the friends relations of the current group but I couldn't find a way to do it without going into in infinite loop of `clear` signals.

So, the solution was to bypass the `clear()` method and directly use the `delete()` method of the manager. I finally use the same approach for the 3 signals. Here's the modified code of the `add_friends` function:

```
def add_friends(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    # On clear, clear all indirect relations of this instance
    if action == 'pre_clear':
        instance.friends.through.objects.filter(from_people__in=instance.friends.all()).delete()

    # Delete all relations of the objects in the removed set
    # (not just the ones related to the instance)
    elif action == 'post_remove':
        instance.friends.through.objects.filter(
                Q(from_people__in=pk_set) | Q(to_people__in=pk_set)
            ).delete()

    # Clear all relations of People moved from one group to another
    elif action == 'pre_add' and pk_set:
        if instance.pk in pk_set:
            raise ValueError(_(u"You can't add self as a friend."))
        instance.friends.through.objects.filter(
                (Q(from_people__in=pk_set) & ~Q(to_people=instance.pk)) |
                (Q(to_people__in=pk_set) & ~Q(from_people=instance.pk))
            ).delete()

    # Add all indirect relations of this instance
    elif action == 'post_add' and pk_set:
        manager = instance.friends.through.objects
        # Get all the pk pairs
        pk_set.add(instance.pk)
        pk_set.update(instance.friends.all().values_list('pk', flat=True))
        pairs = set(permutations(pk_set, 2))
        # Get the pairs already in the DB
        vals = manager.values_list('from_people', 'to_people')
        vals = vals.filter(from_people__in=pk_set, to_people__in=pk_set)
        # Keep only pairs that are not in DB
        pairs = pairs - set(vals)

        # Add them
        for from_pk, to_pk in pairs:
            manager.create(from_people_id=from_pk, to_people_id=to_pk)

m2m_changed.connect(add_friends, sender=People.friends.through)
```